# Webservice to Sqlite Windows 8 Metro

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am creating an windows metro UI App in which i want to consume a webservice and put the values in Sqlite cos if network not available means i can fetch details from it. Is it possible? is there any tool to directly convert values from Sql server values to .s3db sqlite db?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: are you asking how to a) convert SQL Server data to SQLite, or b) consume a web service and put the results into SQLite?

Comment: Yes you are right I want them both.. I can do it for Android.. Now I want to do it in Metro App..